# In random forest, what happens if I add features that are correlated?

Tags: random-forest

I'm training a random forest, trying to predict market shares of future stores on geographical areas. I have many features for these areas, some of which tell similar but different things about one thing.

For example, I know the total number of `accommodations` in the area (*housings* ? not sure of the exact terminology), and I also have 5 others columns which are all linked in the following way :

number of `main accommodations` + number of `secondary accommodations` + number of `holiday accommodations`

= number of `houses` + number of `flats`

= `accommodations`

I have the feeling that including them all in my model would be wrong... but including them might be important... Any hint on how I should handle this ? Would it be a good idea to include `accommodations` as absolute value and include all the other five but as % (of `accommodations`) and not as absolute values ?

In a similar fashion, I also have the total number of `households` of the area, the `total income` of the area, and the `average income` of households in the area (so that `households` * `average income` = `total income`). I have the feeling using the average and not the total income would be a better idea, but how can I be sure I'm right ?

(I guess I could train three random forests using the average income only, the total income only, and both, and see how they perform on cross validation, but is there a rule of thumb that I should know of which can make me go faster ?)

Thanks

(In case it's relevant, I'm using `R` and the `randomForest` package)

Comment: The great thing about random forests is that correlated features are much less a problem than with, for instance, OLS or even bagged trees since each individual tree is constructed using only a subset of the available features.

Comment: Technically, each individual *split* in the resulting tree is constructed using only a subset of the available features.

Comment: I know, but doesn't having multiple correlated features increase the chance of having trees built using them ? Therefore artificially increasing the weight of these features in the resulting ensemble ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are asking 2 questions:

1/ How to assess whether 2 sets of features give better results?

You answer is correct, perform cross validation in each case and see which one perform the best and what is the error variance. The rule of thumb is not to include feature that are too correlated (there is no good way to define too correlated, trial and error is the best). 0.9 correlation is usually considered being very high. Also, if you have features of the type A + B = C, you should only include a pair i.e. (A,C), (B,C) or (A,B). But you can include some features like A/C which will describe something different and might not be correlated at all with other variables. Whether you should use (A/C,B/C) or (A,B) completely depends on your problem and a good place to start is your knowledge of the problem and logic (if your variable is more related to % or actual counts...).

2/ Now about adding correlated features.

If you are trying to build explanatory models then it could be bad and you have to be very careful. But this is not what you are trying to do, your model seems to be purely predictive. Thus the main issue when you add correlated features is that you have more or less twice the same information. There are 2 problems with that:

- Related to random forest. Since random forest samples some features to build each tree, the information contained in correlated features is twice as much likely to be picked than any other information contained in other features. This could be a problem if you have a large % of correlated features.
- Not Related to random forest. In general, when you are adding correlated features, it means that they linearly contains the same information and thus it will reduce the robustness of your model. Each time you train your model, your model might pick one feature or the other to "do the same job" i.e. explain some variance, reduce entropy, etc... So each time you train, depending on your split of data, you are actually building different models.

Now that being said, correlated features in random forest are usually well handle because of sampling and bagging. Also 2 correlated features might contains very different information and thus both might be crucial to your model, especially in the case of non-linear models like random forest.

Comment: Ok, that's what I thought, thanks. Considering the fact that it takes time to run and we're many people taking turns using the server, I can't try too many long things, so I'm thinking about making tries with few trees in the random forests to see which combination performs better. Could it be possible that one combination that performs the best on few trees would be (significantly) outperformed by another combination when the number of trees increases ? (If so, is it likely ?)

Comment: Define small number of trees ? You should train and look at your OOB estimate and stop when it is good enough. Random Forest power comes from the many trees so training with a few might give you unreliable results indeed (lot of variance).

Comment: If my post answer your question, please tag it as answer and upvote it. Thanks!

Comment: I'll have to check again on monday, but small would be in the hundreds (trees). I can see the OOB estimate while the algorithm is running ? How ? (PS : can't upvote yet, my score on CV is too low)

Comment: I think that if you set do.trace=TRUE, RandomForest should print info while running